# Camel - camelContext - RabbitMQ component - what should be the value for exchangeName?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am using [RabbitMQ component](https://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) of Camel, for Camel routing. While creating a queue from RabbitMQ console I have not explicitly mentioned any **exchange name**. But the url expects the **exchangeName**

```
rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?[options]
```

What should be the value of **exchangeName** for a default queue? I tried to get the message from RabbitMQ console to see whether it has any **exchangeName**, and here is the snapshot

[image]

From this I could not derive the exchangeName. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The exchange name is something that you can specify, for the default you can use this:

> ...we were using a default exchange, which we identify by the empty string ("").

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

So your code would look something like this:

```
rabbitmq://hostname[:port]?[options]
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if the [camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) explicitly stated that `exchangeName` is optional.